# Updating an item in array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to update values I have in a PHP array. It seems that the values are not updating whenever I assign new values to a certain item. Here's my code:

```
$actions = array(
    array('action' => 'Action1', 'value' => '0'),
    array('action' => 'Action2', 'value' => '0'),
);

foreach($actions as $item){
    if($item['action'] == 'Action1'){
        $item['value'] = 20;
    }
}
```

After doing this foreach loop, the array remains as is. With all values having the 0 value.

Comment: Sir, this website is different than other Q&A websites when you choose answer just check it as the correct instead of updating the title to `[SOLVED]` and add thanks in the body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you us a for each loop you are not updating the original array.  You are just updating the `$item` var in the scope of the loop

You need to pass by reference rather than value

```
foreach ($actions as &$item) {
}
```

Notice the `&` before the `$item` this will cause your changes to update the original array.

Comment: @StanleySemilla Do not forget it to accept as an answer if it answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    foreach($actions as $key => $val){
    if($val['action'] == 'Action1'){
        $actions[$key]['value'] = 20;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are modifying a copy of the variable, what you want is one of the following:

```
foreach($actions as &$item){    //<== add "&" reference to the $item that now when ever you change it the actions will change 
    if($item['action'] == 'Action1'){
        $item['value'] = 20;
    }
}
```

OR

```
foreach($actions as $key => $item){    
    if($item['action'] == 'Action1'){
        $actions[$key]['value'] = 20; // directly access $action and modify the value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the answers above, you may also try this:

```
foreach(array_keys($actions) as $key){
    $item = &$actions[$key];
    if($item['action'] == 'Action1'){
        $item['value'] = 20;
    }
}
```

I remember the the method like

```
foreach($actions as &$item)
```

may cause some wired problem under certain circumstance. I've encountered once in Drupal but cannot remember where.